# How to check blood sugar on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, how-to, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, choleh-sick

[Diabetes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diabetes_mellitus) is a חולי שיש בו סכנה, an illness that poses a danger to life<sup>1</sup>. As such, everything necessary for caring for diabetes must be done on Shabbos, even if it includes איסורי תורה. (see [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 328](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1596), [Rambam, Hilchot Shabbos 2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3102.htm), שמירת שבת כהלכתה, ch. 32)

However, if it makes no difference to the speed/efficacy in which care is provided, one should minimize the amount of חילול שבת, both in the amount of actions done, as well as in the severity of the prohibitions violated (Biblical vs. rabbinic). [Shmiras Shabbos K'Hilchasa, 32:27-29]
Therefore, [blood sugar testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diabetes_management#Monitoring), which is a medical necessity for PWD (especially those with [insulin-dependent DM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diabetes_mellitus_type_1)), must be done on Shabbos, but the prohibitions violated should be limited.

**How should one check blood sugar on Shabbos, while minimizing Shabbos violations?**

---

<sup>1</sup><sup><sub>Whether due to [hypo or hyperglycemia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diabetes_management#Hypo_and_hyperglycemia), both which can are preventable -- given that they are discovered before they happen, like by [blood sugar check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diabetes_management#Monitoring).</sub></sup>

Comment: I've [asked and answered my own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), partially so that I could have a page to link to when I'm trying to explain this, but also partially so that I could hear other people's answers, in case anyone else wants to answer.

Comment: http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2015/01/treating-diabetes-on-shabbos.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this is a [how-to](/questions/tagged/how-to) question, I will answer it with practical advice. Questions about the particular halachos mentioned in passing may be [asked separately](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Here's what I've been told to do, with illustrative pictures. **Before changing anything about what you do personally, you should talk to both your rabbi and your doctor.** What is written here is just practical advice, gleaned from years of experience (and conversations with [Rabbi Hirsch Meisels](http://friendswithdiabetes.org/)).

### Step 0

**What are we dealing with?**
[image: blood testing set]
A: blood sugar meter (measures blood sugar levels)
B<sub>1</sub>: strip container (contains strips)
B<sub>2</sub>: testing strips (brings blood into meter)
C: lancet (draws blood)

### Step 1

**Inserting strip**

In order to use the meter, the strip has to be inserted. Doing so turns the meter on, and possibly created a *kli* (vessel), as neither piece is usable by itself. As such, a *shinui* should be used to insert the strip into the meter.

Meter with strip in it:

[image: meter and strip]

Suggested *shinui* (insert halfway, and push against a table):

[image: meter and strip shinui]

### Step 2

**Drawing blood ("lancing")**

Drawing blood to test is usually done by pressing the button on the lancet with a finger, like this:

[image: regular lancing]

To replace this possible איסור דאורייתא (Biblical prohibition) with a שינוי (different way of doing it, considered halachically to be less severe), lancing should be done with a knuckle, like this:

[image: shinui lancing]

*Anecdotally, I've used about everything, from elbows to forehead. (Yes, forehead* :P *)*

#### Step 2.5

**Squeezing blood**

Squeezing blood out of the wound (in case there is not enough from just the lancing) is problematic on Shabbos, due to the prohibition of *dash* (the weirdest form of squeezing liquid from solid you're ever likely to see), so it should be done with a *shinui* if possible.

Regular squeeze:

[image: regular squeeze]

Suggested *shinui*: use the lancet

[image: shinui squeeze]

Then put the drop of blood on the strip, like normal, and collect the result. Do ***not*** turn off the meter after use, because this serves no purpose on Shabbos (unless the battery will die, and this meter is needed for more tests over the course of Shabbos).

Comment: I wonder if putting the drop of blood on the strip like normal is dyeing, and if so whether letting it drip onto the strip from above would (a) act as a sort of shinui and (b) be ok medically.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Interesting idea; I'd never thought about that. I don't think it would be a problem of dyeing though, because I'm pretty sure that nothing gets colored -- just a small space in the strip gets filled.

Comment: Oh, the strip is a container rather than being absorbent?  I didn't know that.  Is it worth mentioning that in your last paragraph, or is that something that would be obvious to anybody for whom this is a practical matter?

Comment: Your Shinui in Step 2 might not be effective as a Shinui because the needle is still poking in the same way.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm not 100% sure on that count....I'll check it out, but I've pulled apart enough used strips to be reasonably sure that there is a space between the top and bottom halves of the strip, where the blood goes in. On some strips (eg Freestyle) the place where the blood goes is black, so it's hard to tell; but on others (eg OneTouch, Bayer), there is a clear layer of plastic so whatever coloring takes place, it's just blood showing through the clear plastic. Further research is called for.

Comment: @DoubleAA I hear what you're saying. I haven't looked at the relevant halachos inside, recently.....but this is what I've always been told to do by many people. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @Shokhet Ask a non-Jew? Set it on a timer to poke every 5 minutes all of Shabbat? I know we may allow deoraitas if it's actually necessary (and I bet with careful dietary planning one could greatly minimize risk) but we sure do try to avoid it.

Comment: @DoubleAA Neither of those is very practical, though. ....I'll ask someone I know who has told *many* people in the past to do exactly this, why he said it ( *I think I may even know who he was quoting when he said it, but I'll have to check* )

Comment: @Shokhet Some say it is a valid shinui, others say it isn't. (This is a standing machloket achronim.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I'll look into it. Do you have some starting sources?

Comment: @Shokhet It's been a while but try searching for "eglei tal shinui" I think it's the Eglei Tal who is the dominant position on one side.